# How to insert a field containing "def" to the field containing "abcghi"

Tags: excel, split, field, addition

I would like to insert string inside to another field with $$.

**Example:**

| A1 | B1 |
| --- | --- |
| def | abcghi |

**Expected output**

| A1 | B1 |
| --- | --- |
| def | abcdefghi |

I tried something like
`abc$A$1def` but it did not work

Answer (score 1):

I found a way:

```
="abc"&$A$1&"ghi"
```